# Preference of Axioms

Tags: probability-theory

Why do some people prefer the following axiom (e.g. [deFinetti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_de_Finetti))

> If $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of sets and $A,B$ are disjoint then $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$

over the following

> Suppose $A_1, A_2 ,\dots \in \mathcal{B}$ and are pairwise disjoint. Then $$P \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}  A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(A_i)$$

Comment: Are you missing a $P$ in (2)? I guess so. And I'd say (1) is a special case of (2) if $A$ and $B$ make up the algebra and (1) implyies (2) via induction. Or is your problem the $\infty$ vs. only two elements?

Comment: You need more than induction to prove 2 from 1.

Comment: One reason would be to talk about the probability that two natural numbers are co-prime.  But I doubt that's what Bruno de Finetti had in mind.